# "Thank you for coming" and "Thank you for your coming"

Tags: verbs, nouns, expressions, pronouns, gerunds

Consider "Thank you for coming" and "Thank you for your coming".

Would the latter one be grammatical? Why? Is it possible to recognize latter "coming" as noun? Some say you need no pronoun because it is mentioned before.

Comment: "Thank you for your coming" is Japanese-English and Chinese-English. "Thank you for coming" is idiomatic and natural native English-speaker English. They both mean the same thing, but native English-speakers would not say "Thank you for your coming".

Answer (score 3):

The first example is correct, as you are obviously aware.

The second has slightly seedy connotations - the coming belonging to you. In this day and age, with 'come' having some interesting meanings, I don't think it would be entirely appropriate to use this phrase.

Comment: With the inevitable reply _Thank you for having me._

Comment: Four year later, I finally got your *seedy* joke.

Answer (score 2):

Your first example is a participle, similar to *I am grateful that you came*, which is perfectly normal.  The second would be a gerund, similar to *I am grateful for your arrival*, and sounds just as strange as that sentence, perhaps because your arrival is less your responsibility than the decision to make the trip; the arrival will depend on other factors. The second, as Barrie pointed out, also has unfortunate connotations.

Comment: How would it work with "We thank you for your coming here at this late hour"? I believe that this would be fine in BE similar to "We appreciate your coming here".

Answer (score -1):

"Thank you for coming" can be used when greeting or saying goodbye to someone at an event that they were invited to.

"Thank you for your coming" is wrong because the possessive "your" always needs a noun following it (your bag, your phone, your courage, etc...).  In this case, you have a verb in the present progressive tense, and it's therefore grammatically incorrect.

Comment: There is no such thing as “a verb in the present progressive tense”. The *-ing* inflection of a verb is a non-finite inflection functioning as the head of a verb phrase but which in turn can serve as a noun phrase. So “His **telling me** was the very last straw” is perfectly grammatical. This was historically classed as a gerund use, which is a verb phrase acting in place of a noun. *Telling me* is the gerund phrase which as a noun phrase can take the *his* possessive determiner standing in for the VP’s subject (*him* also works) and have the entire NP serve as the subject of that sentence.

Answer (score -3):

Sorry to say that second one is completely natural for native speakers. Please review some grammar of the English language: http://www.getitwriteonline.com/archive/022205posscasegerunds.htm

Comment: this is untrue. @user21497 was right

Comment: The advice at that link is highly questionable!