# "Thank you for your coming" and "Thank you for your understanding"

Tags: verbs, nouns, pronouns, possessives, gerunds

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Thank you for coming” and “Thank you for your coming”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/85119/thank-you-for-coming-and-thank-you-for-your-coming)

The first one seems ungrammatical, as pointed by some of native speakers. But the latter one seems relatively recognized as grammatical sentence. Considering both "coming" and "understanding" nouns, both sentence seems grammatical to me. Or "coming" never be a noun?
Could you show me other example with different verbs?

Comment: Answers and comments on [your previous question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/85119/thank-you-for-coming-and-thank-you-for-your-coming) indicated that the first ("your coming") **is** grammatical, but not idiomatic because of the potential for misunderstanding and unfortunate connotations. Such connotations do not apply to "understanding".

Comment: Why have you opened an almost exact duplicate of your earlier question?  Just edit the original for clarity.